# MLFinLab package for financial machine learning from Hudson and Thames

Tags: software, soft-question

Has anyone tried MFinLab from Hudson and Thames? The full license is not cheap, so I was wondering if there was any feedback.

([Github repository](https://github.com/hudson-and-thames/mlfinlab))

Comment: Its free for using on as-is basis, only license for extra documentation, example and assistance I believe

Answer (score 3):

Mlfinlab covers, and is the official source of, all the major contributions of Lopez de Prado, even his most recent. Given that most researchers nowadays make their work public domain, however, it is way over-priced. Even charging for the actual technical documentation, hiding them behind padlock,  is nothing short of greedy.

Comment: Is it just Lopez de Prado's stuff? For $250/month, that is not so wonderful.

Comment: If you run through the table of contents, you will not see a module that was not based on an article or technique (co-) authored by him. Unless other starters were brought into the fold since they first began to charge for it earlier this year

Comment: Completely agree with @develarist, I would recomend getting the books. They provide all the code and intuition behind the library.

Comment: MlFinLab is not only the work of Lopez de Prado but also contains many implementations from the Journal of Financial Data Science and the Journal of Portfolio Management.

Comment: The answer above was based on versions of mfinlab prior to it being a paid service when they added on several other scientists' work to the package. Originally it was primarily centered around de Prado's works but not anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I just started using the library.
So far I am pretty satisfied with the content, even though there are some small bugs here and there, and you might have to rewrite some of the functions to make them really robust.
Concerning the price I completely disagree that it is overpriced. If you think that you are paying $250/month for just a bunch of python functions replicating a book, yes it might seem overpriced. But if you think of the time it can save you so that you can dedicate your effort to the actual research, then it is a very good deal.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! What sorts of bugs have you found? (I am not asking for line numbers, but is it corner cases, typos, or?!)

Comment: For example in the implementation of the z_score_filter, there is a sign bug : the filter only filters occurences where the price is above the threshold (condition formula should be abs(price-mean) > thres*std instead of price > mean + thres*std

Comment: yeah lots of the functions they left open-ended or strict on datatype inputs, making the user have to hardwire their own work-arounds. Support by email is not good either

Comment: Although I don't find it that inconvenient. It just forces you to have an active and critical approach, result is that you are more aware of the implementation details, which is a good thing.

Comment: @develarist What do you mean by "open ended or strict on datatype inputs"? I am a little puzzled...

Comment: "Note that you can just pay for a month or two, take the library as is, or extend it and you end paying not that much." This is a violation of their licence agreement and all IP built ontop of it will belong to the firm. 

Be sure to read the license carefully!

Comment: @ZelliZello, I am co-author of mlfinlab package and responsible for z-score filter implementation. Initially, the filter was developed to capture price spikes only, however, it is a very good point that it should capture sharp price declines also. We have put it into our issues list and will try to release bug fix soon. Thank you very much for your review and comments!